# Facebook image sharing not working in android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-access-token, android-facebook

I have made an app in that I want to share an image and a text ,I have successfully get the login Dialog of facebook..But after Login it gives me error that **Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.**
What should i do to solve it.My code is as below ,Please help needed..

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void loginToFacebook() {

            mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
            Session session = facebook.getSession();

            if (access_token != null) {
                SessionState st = SessionState.OPENED;
                facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                Exception e = new FacebookError("Error");
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::aCEESS TOKEN::::::::;;"
                        + access_token);
                 postToWall();
                /*fbImageSubmit(facebook, big_img, "3sMAniquines", "Maniquines",
                        cat_nem, big_img);*/

                onSessionStateChange(session, st, e);
                Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());

            }
            if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            }

            if (expires != 0) {
                facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }

            if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                facebook.authorize(this,
                        new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                        new DialogListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                // Function to handle cancel event
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                // Function to handle complete event
                                // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                                editor.putString("access_token",
                                        facebook.getAccessToken());
                                editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                        facebook.getAccessExpires());
                                editor.commit();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError error) {
                                // Function to handle error

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                                // Function to handle Facebook errors

                            }

                        });
            }
 * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void postToWall() {

        // post on user's wall.
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the access token of logged user for maintaining Session for further task.

according to your code following code will give you currently logged in user's access token.

```
String access_token = Const.fb.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: I have saved in my prefrences but where to use it,Please tell me ..Thyankk you ,Please save me

Comment: See this link- [android-facebook-connect-tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/)
It can help you.

Comment: @priyanka-I already gone thru this post..But its only for text sharing i want to share image too...Can you please tell me what changes should made in this post to share an image please..

Comment: @user3710354 useful or not?

Comment: Priyanka-I am having no idea how to attach image that way..So i have used this code..Can you please tell me what changes should i made in existing code to attach image pls?wait i am editing my question